# how to pass the variable with space as parameter in onclick function in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the variable with space as parameter in onclick function. 
This is my table value with space :"file name sample"

```
   echo '<input type=checkbox name=".$next."  id=".$next." onclick=my1(this.form,this.checked,".$cid.",'".$vfet['file_name']."','".$id."');>';
```

script code

```
echo ('<script>
                function my1(a,ischeck,cid,file,eid)
                {
                alert("welcome");
                 alert("select"+ischeck);
                 alert("file"+file);
                 }
         </script>');
```

file value is passed nicely if the value has no space.

Comment: First fix the code, it seems invalid to me. Change to this `echo '<input type=checkbox name="'.$next.'"  id="'.$next.'" onclick="my1(this.form,this.checked,\''.$cid.'\',\''.$vfet['file_name'].'\',\''.$id.'\');">';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the html legal and put double quotes around the onclick value - at the moment the space is making the browser think it is a separate attribute.

You are also mixing up your single and double quotes a bit:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$next.'"  id="'.$next.'" onclick="my1(this.form,this.checked,'.$cid.',\''.$vfet['file_name'].'\',\''.$id.'\');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

just try

`"'.$cid.'"`  and not `".$cid."`  or with the '\'